# Can you remarry if your spouse is dead?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Title sums it up: can you remarry if your spouse is dead?

Comment: Are you planning to kill your spouse...?

Comment: meybe ;) hahaha

Comment: only if it's with Pamela Anderson

Comment: Maybe you can make it look like an accident.. I don't know.. :)

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wives_of_Henry_VIII

Answer (score 11):

Yes you can: [source](http://elderscrolls.wikia.com/wiki/Marriage#Divorce) from the Elder scrolls wikia

The above suggests you need to use some console commands too, but most people are reporting that you just need to put her down and remarry.

Update:
I just found [this](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Bugs) on UESP

> Murdering your spouse may result in not being able to remarry (confirmed on PC, Xbox 360 and PS3)

So it seems very hit and miss.

Comment: I can see people thinking up many inventive ways to kill their spouses to test if it will allow them to remarry.

Comment: In order to level up my ebony blade I repeatedly killed and console resurrected my wife, Lydia. Now she doesn't have spouse options. Is she counted as dead so I can remarry?

Answer (score 1):

No you can not remarry, to my knowledge, if you kill your wife in-game.