# How do I deal with a runaway bride?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I killed my first wife once I found out there is a mercenary you can marry who gives you up to 300 gold a day (in Whiterun). The only requirement, of course, being that I had to hire her first. So I hired her, and then I popped the question, to which she replied the usual: tell the priest to arrange the wedding.

When we reached Riften I told her to wait, just outside the bee and barb, and arranged the wedding. I went through the process, and the second it finished she left, I followed but as I left she was nowhere to be seen. I have tried going back to my house, the pub where I hired her and that same spot in Riften about 6 times each now, some during the day, some during the night and cannot find her at all.

Now this isn't to much of a problem because I can re-marry...oh wait, to remarry, my spouse has to die, so I can't claim gold off her and can't remarry, and the autosaves have been used up fast travelling to the places I thought she might've been. My last save is something like 6 levels ago, and I don't want to have to load it.

What should I do about this situation?

Comment: Lemme get this straight... You killed the love of your life for 300 gold/day... and your new wife obviously heard and went into hiding... and now you want us to help you hunt her down? Sure, sounds like a plan! :P

Comment: You can remarry? Get thee over to [this question](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/can-you-remarry-if-your-spouse-is-dead) and tell us how!

Comment: Like a true black widow..er.

Comment: Same happened to me. Try going back to the Temple of Mara, that's where mine was.

Comment: This is a strange question because you cannot remarry once your original spouse dies. Also there is no spouse that gives you 300 gold per day.

Answer (score 25):

This happened to my wife, Aela the Huntress, when I got married.

What I found out, is that she teleported outside Riften's walls, and then began a slow walk back towards Jorvaskyr. (I could track her location because "Ask the leaders of the Companions about Work" was in my questlog).

Perplexingly, when I fast-traveled back to whiterun, I saw Vilkas and Farkas (who were both at the wedding) but no Aela. For whatever reason, she was traveling more slowly than any of us.

What this boils down to is that your newly wed wife is going back to her default location - so you were right to check the pub where you originally hired her - but wives tend to go about this **extremely** slowly.

My suggestion? Wait a few in-game days and then check the pub again.

Comment: "But wives tend to go about this extremely slowly" Wow, this game is very realistic!

Answer (score 11):

i just found this:
[Marriage bugs](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage#Bugs)

> in some cases the NPC spouse disappears after exiting the Temple of Mara, unless you exit dialogue with Maramal and rush after them before they reach the door. If this happens, you may find your new spouse in the spot where you first met; you can then talk to the person to decide where you'll both live. In some cases, the spouse seems to disappear from the game completely, in which case your only option is to load a saved game from before the wedding and talk to your spouse before he or she leaves the temple.

which suggests that sometimes they do just disappear!