# I've lost  my wife. Where can I find her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a runaway bride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/how-do-i-deal-with-a-runaway-bride)

I seem to have lost my wife. I married Brelyna Maryon, but haven't seen her since the ceremony in Riften.

She doesn't seem to have returned to the college. She isn't at my house in Whiterun. Not sure where else she might be...

Anyway, I figure some Lover's Comfort would be useful. And it'd be nice to cash in on her income too.

Any ideas where/how I might find her?

Comment: Every good marriage starts with you losing your wife. Wait...

Answer (score 3):

I did the same thing! I left the ceremony, and hadn't seen her for a few days.

Turns out, I had to talk to her about where we wanted to live first. I found her walking around inside the Temple of Mara, and when I got close enough, the game immediately put me into conversation with her. I had the option for us to move into the house I owned, or for me to move in with her (I assume at the college?). After that, she turned up at my house, as expected.

Comment: I had the exact same spouse. I lost her right after the ceremony. I searched 2 houses and her old room. I came back to the temple and waited till 8am. she poped up and started nagging me. I never should have gotten married. sigh.