# I've lost my wife. How can I find her?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a runaway bride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/how-do-i-deal-with-a-runaway-bride)

So.. I married Brelyna. After the wedding ceremony I agreed to live at her house and I can't seem to find her house. Does she even have a house, or does she live at the college?

Comment: Hi Dusty and welcome to Stack Exchange! There's no need to include the name of your game in the title of your question, as that's what our tags are for, so I've gone ahead and edited it out. Hope you enjoy the site!

Answer (score 2):

She lives at the college. When you're going up to the college, enter the "Hall of Attainment" on your left. Once in there, she occupies the first bed on the left.