# Why isn't my wife at our house?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do I deal with a runaway bride?](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/how-do-i-deal-with-a-runaway-bride)

I married Jenassa and chose to live at her house (I have to live there first then move to one of my own houses to get the Lover's Comfort bonus with her). Since she doesn't have her own house the game sends me to her default location, The Drunken Huntsman. Even the Misc. Quest "Visit your spouse's house" was considered complete when I entered. But I've waited for days using the Wait option as well as traveling in and out of the building and back and forth from Riften, but she's never there. I've checked Whiterun Stables because I've heard about her default location sometimes glitching to being there but no luck. Is this a glitch? She's my follower as well as my wife so I sort of need to find her.

Comment: Check the Jarl's bedchamber, he might be exericising his right of "Prima Nocta"