# I lost my husband

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

So I lost my husband, I have looked for people having similar problems, but that didn't help. We lived in Whiterun first, then we moved to Riften, no problems in both cities. I left for a few ingame months, came back he wasn't there anymore. I looked around in both Whiterun and Riften couldn't find him, even in around the companions. I married the sweet brother [**Farkas**](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Farkas). Any idea where he could have gone? I've looked in my misc' quest and even after I married I still had the thing saying to, 'speak with maramal about arranging your wedding' and I tryed to talk to him but the option is never there. But farkas showed up both times I moved and we had no problems, but after moving to Riften he just dissappeared over a long time.

I have none of the add-ons or mods to skyrim. And I play on xbox 360.I'm really not sure what to do, last time I saw him was 19 levels ago. That's alot of lost data if I go back. I don't know if others have the problem, I looked it up and couldn't find any information, so I'm asking. I waited between going to locatetions to see If he was just going slow, and didn't fast travel. He still never showed, thats all the details I cam think of.

Comment: Sometimes Rochelle the Red will kidnap your spouse and take them to a nearby dungeon - have you checked for a Ransom Note?

Comment: Look at this page, http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Rochelle_the_Red does that help?


If you provide us with the name of the NPC you married we can help, 'the sweet brother' just isn't enough information for us to know who it is.


Are you playing on the PC?

Comment: Did you check the pod directly across from yours?

Comment: The pod??? What is that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I deal with a runaway bride?](http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37913/how-do-i-deal-with-a-runaway-bride)

Comment: Farkas has quite a lot of available quests he is a part of. Did you trigger any of them? (I added a link to the uesp wiki page for farkas).

Comment: Also, how long has he been missing. (In ingame days) sometimes they take a very very very (very?) long time to walk back to their starting location.

Comment: Missing for a few ingame weeks, and I did all his quest, and couldn't find one in my quest log thing that involves him