# What is the easiest female human spouse to get?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Ok so I just married Camilla to test a previous question of mine. I got married to her in the temple and requested she moved into the house I bought in whiterun. Well after so I waited twelve in game hours then fast traveled to whiterun. She was not at my house. So I checked riverwood. Not there. I've tried to fix this glitch and it's not working. So I'm reloading my save from before I bought the house. Now who is the easiest female human spouse to get? I'd rather not see the same glitch or otherwise again if at all possible.

Comment: Are you playing on PC or on a console? PC can just console command somebody.

Comment: I'm playing it on Xbox 360

Comment: Also, see this other question about your wife not being at the house as you expected: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37913/108003

Answer (score 6):

There's a table with all the possible spouses found on the [Elder Scrolls Pages article on Marriage](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Marriage). I removed the non-humans from the female list and copied it below:

```
NPC Name                Race        Location                                Wife's Property         Follower    Merchant    Trainer Conditions for Marriage
Aela the Huntress       Nord        Whiterun (Jorrvaskr)                    Bed (Jorrvaskr)         Yes                     Complete the Companions Questline
Aeri                    Nord        Anga’s Mill                             Aeri's House            No                      Work for her by chopping firewood
Anwen                   Redguard    Markarth (Temple of Dibella)            [None]                  No                      Complete The Heart of Dibella
Camilla Valerius        Imperial    Riverwood (Riverwood Trader)            Riverwood Trader        No          General     Complete The Golden Claw
Gilfre                  Imperial    Mixwater Mill                           Gilfre's House          No                      Work for her by chopping firewood
HilundDB                Nord        Thirsk Mead Hall                        Bed (Thirsk Mead Hall)  No                      Complete her favor: Hilund Favor Quest
Iona                    Nord        Riften (Honeyside)                      Bed (Honeyside)         Yes                     Become Thane of the Rift
Jordis the Sword-Maiden Nord        Solitude (Proudspire Manor)             Bed (Proudspire Manor)  Yes                     Become Thane of Haafingar
Lydia                   Nord        Whiterun (Dragonsreach or Breezehome)   Bed (Breezehome)        Yes                     Complete Dragon Rising and purchase Breezehome.
Mjoll the Lioness       Nord        Riften                                  Aerin's House           Yes                     Complete Grimsever's Return
Morwen                  Nord        Skaal Village                           Morwen's House          No                      Complete her favor: Skaal Village Dialogue
Muiri                   Breton      Markarth (The Hag's Cure)               The Hag's Cure          No          Apothecary  Complete Mourning Never Comes (Player must kill Nilsine as well. Must be proprietor of the store to sell Apothecary merchandise.)
Njada Stonearm          Nord        Whiterun (Jorrvaskr)                    [None]                  Yes                     Complete the Companions Questline
Orla                    Nord        Markarth (Temple of Dibella)            [None]                  No                      Complete The Heart of Dibella
Rayya                   Redguard    Falkreath (Jarl's Longhouse)            [None]                  Yes                     Become Thane of Falkreath
Ria                     Imperial    Whiterun (Jorrvaskr)                    [None]                  Yes                     Complete the Companions Questline
Senna                   Breton      Markarth (Temple of Dibella)            [None]                  No                      Complete The Heart of Dibella
Sylgja                  Nord        Shor’s Stone                            Sylgja's House          No          Clothing    Complete her favor: Special Delivery
Temba Wide-Arm          Nord        Ivarstead                               [None]                  No          General     Complete her favor: Chop Wood or Grin and Bear It
Uthgerd the Unbroken    Nord        Whiterun (The Bannered Mare)            Uthgerd's House         Yes                     Challenge her to a brawl and win
Viola Giordano          Imperial    Windhelm (Candlehearth Hall)            Viola Giordano's House  No                      Rat out Revyn Sadri during his favor
Ysolda                  Nord        Whiterun (Open Market)                  Ysolda's House          No          General     Bring her one Mammoth Tusk as a favor
```

Which one of these is easiest will depend on your character, where you are in the game, what you've done and acquired, and so on.

If you've already done the required quest for someone, like completing the Companions quest line for Aela, then that would probably be easiest.

Assuming you've done no quests, the easiest would probably be Ysolda, if you have a mammoth tusk or know where to get one, or Uthgerd, as you simply have to beat her in a brawl. If you find brawling difficult or too time-consuming, you could lower the difficulty level first. Both of these women are found in Whiterun.

Iona and Mjoll are both in Riften, where the temple is, but both require completing quests.

Comment: If you want to brawl with Uthgerd, you'll probably want to lower the difficulty.  Brawling on Legendary is just bad...

Comment: @Nelson I find brawling comically easy. I normally don't even get hit.

Comment: It's not an issue of dying.  It's an issue of how much time it takes.  You do almost no damage on Legendary difficulty.  You should try it without the +punch damage gloves... it takes a while...

Comment: @Nelson I may have had additional damage gloves before, that's not normal. You're right it takes a while. Just kite them until it's over. If you don't think that's easy, then of course that wouldn't be the easiest one for you.

Comment: Never said it is "hard".  I just said it is "bad" as in really, really boring and tedious... :)  At least I find it to be really boring to brawl for 10 minutes.  Plus if you hit another person you just got yourself into a huge mess of trouble.