# My wife tried to kill me! What did I do wrong?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I got married and during the ceremony it felt like my wife just kinda walked out in the middle of the whole deal right after saying "I do".  I talked to my (RL) dad and he told me that she walks home to her house after this and you just have to wait it out and meet her there.  I spent the next couple of RL days periodically stopping by the house, and no one was ever there.

Eventually I picked up a new female companion to go fight with me.  Later, a quest led me back to go rough up the priest who married us, and when I walked in there door, there was my wife, super pissed and ready to rock.  I tried to run, but she kept following me and I was like, no baby, I need to rough up the priest, you hold tight... but nah, she wasn't having any of it.  Naturally I took this opportunity to test out the new level 100 destro spell I had just earned.  Destro 1, wife 0.

A lot of things happened since we got married and I suppose it was our lack of communication that played a big role, but since she's dead now, does anyone have any insight why we were unable to reconcile?  I would like to avoid the same end in my future relationships.

---

EDIT: per the comments and the first answer, my wife was the lady you have to fight in the Inn on the far side of the market in white run.  Uthgerd (spelling?) or something like that.  In hindsight, it's obvious that marriage would end in domestic violence, but I'm still curious what set her off.

Comment: After hearing what you did to your first wife, do you expect anyone to marry you again?!?!

Comment: Did you leave the toilet seat up...?

Comment: Sounds like a mother-in-law issue is behind this :)

Comment: It would help to at least know who your wife was, so people can determine what might trigger her to become hostile.

Comment: In regards to what @OrigamiRobot said, you will not be able to re-marry in any case.. just so you know.

Comment: @James do you have evidence of that?

Comment: @NickLarsen http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/37120/can-you-remarry-if-your-spouse-is-dead A question that has already been asked, a few times, on here.

Answer (score 10):

The walking out after saying "I do" part is normal. Lives in Skyrim are too short for drawn-out ceremonies. Spouses will return to their daily routines, not necessarily their houses, until you move to your own property, in which case they'll (usually?) stay inside.

There are some conditions under which a spouse may attempt to kill you. For example, [Mjoll the Lioness will attempt to kill you if your murder of Aerin becomes known](http://www.uesp.net/wiki/Skyrim:Mjoll_the_Lioness). Even though the creep moves in with you if you leave Riften.

Comment: I didnt even get as far as "I do". As soon as possible, she legged it. Eventually I found her, and I mean eventually. One of the quests respawned her. An apparent bug.

Answer (score 1):

Talk to her before she leaves, then ask her "where are we going to live", if you already have a house then you'll say "I will live with you" or "I have a place".

Answer (score 0):

This has happened to me also it was because i had rejected the same girl twice so the third time she snapped luckily i was already the thane so i got away.

> Honor to you my thane