# Why am I unable to talk to Brynjolf?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

Once I have finished the quest with Kharliah and that high elf dude, from winterhold I think, I'm supposed to talk to Brynjolf (I think) but, he won't talk to me. Is there someone else I need to contact first? I just can't continue in with the thieves guild till I can do so.

Comment: Edited out the first part of your question. That is answered by http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/37120/8581

Answer (score 3):

You need to meet Karliah in the thieves guild and Both of you talk to Brynjolf to continue that quest line.

Also, please work on your spelling a bit. I have fixed it up where I can but just giving what you typed a once over before you submit a question can be very useful.

Comment: +1 for spelling, though that should really be a comment rather than part of your answer ;)

Comment: @Ktash LOL, Thanks. Ill slide a bit of the +1 over towards being hopefully the correct answer as well ;)

Answer (score 1):

Go to the Ragged Flaggon and talk to Karliah then you will go to the cistern and then Brynjolf will pull out his dagger.Then you and Karliah will talk to him and he will lead you to the vault(the one that says ''requres key'').You will see nothing but some weapons then a new mission will initiate(get the weapons if you wan't to).